# Statistic about Actual vs. Projected

Tags: statistics, percentages

I am trying to show how much a certain thing has exceeded or fallen below its expectation. How do I calculate this? I forgot if this statistic is called Percent Difference or something else, I remember learning it in Chemistry for actual vs. experimental.

Stats:
`Actual Value: 16`
`Projected Value: 11`

How do I calculate that actual value has exceeded the projected expectation by some `x %`?

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia article on the topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want percent error. The formula for this is given by taking the absolute value of the difference between your actual and expected, and then dividing that by the expected to get a relative approximation. Therefore, your formula is

$$\frac{\left|\mathrm{Expected}-\mathrm{Actual}\right|}{\mathrm{Actual}}$$

or

$$\frac{\left|11-16\right|}{11}=\frac{5}{11}=45\% \text{ error}$$

You can then specify that your answer was above the expected result

Comment: Assuming your formula is as intended, the denominator is incorrect.  $$\frac{\left|11-16\right|}{16}=\frac{5}{16}=31.25\% \text{ error}$$

Answer (score 0):

scrblnrd3's answer is incorrect.

It should be:

$$\frac{\text{Actual} - \text{Expected}}{\text{Expected}} = \frac{\text{Actual}}{\text{Expected}} - 1 = \frac{16-11}{11} = 45 \%.$$

If you are considering this from a performance standpoint, you don't take the absolute value. Positive value indicates favorable performance, negative value indicates bad performance.

Sources:

https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/data-science/variance-formula/
https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/budget-variance-vs-actual-variance-analysis

Comment: I am confused, isnt your answer the same as theirs?

Comment: No, it is not. You don't want the absolute value if you want to consider the direction in which a metric has changed (positive or negative). For magnitude, sure, take the absolute value. The accepted answer's equation is also wrong.

Comment: In general, please try to avoid meta commentary in answers.  I would also suggest that you include maybe a sentence or two regarding the signed error.  In my reading of the question, is not at all clear that this is what the asker is seeking (not that it actually makes any difference in this particular case).